# How to create a combined, scrollable List in a Drawer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wan´t to have a **combination of text-widgets and lists inside a drawer**. This content should be scrollable.

Here´s my sourcecode:

```html
 return Drawer(
      child: Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            AppBar(title: Text('Test'),),
            Text('Example 1:'),
            ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _brands.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                    ....);
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  const Divider(height: 5),
            ),
            Text('Another heading')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**What I want to achive:**

- The AppBar is fixed at the top
- The other content below should be scrollable

I´ve tried different ways with Expanded, Columns etc. but I wasn´t able to get this layout up and running as expected. Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a single column with the listview places inside an expanded widget

```dart
return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          AppBar(),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(index.toString());
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  const Divider(height: 5),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

yeilds [image: this]

Answer (score 0):

For short you can wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded` widget, it will fill all available space, but you will able to scroll it. In another case you should wrap ListView with `Container` and set `height` property.

For your example:

```
Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            AppBar(title: Text('Test'),),
            Text('Example 1:'),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: List.generate(100, (index) => index).length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(leading: Text("$index"),);
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                const Divider(height: 5),
              ),
            ),
            Text('Another heading')
          ],
        ),
      ),
```